# Suppose that A is a linear transformation and p is a polynomial. Is it true that if p(λ) is an eigenvalue for p(A). Then λ is an eigenvalue for A?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that A is a linear transformation and p is a polynomial. Is it true that if p(λ) is an eigenvalue for p(A). Then λ is an eigenvalue for A?

I already know that it is not true but I dont know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

which has eigenvalues $1$ and $0$. Let $p(x)=x^2$. Note that $A^2=A$. So $p(A)$ has $1$ and $0$ as eigenvalues. Note also that $p(-1)=(-1)^2=1$, so $p(-1)$ is an eigenvalue for $p(A)$, yet...

Comment: Shouldn't we look like, if p(-1) is an eigenvalue of p(A) then -1 should be an eigenvalue of A. But it is not...

Comment: Exactly. So $p(\lambda)$ being an eigenvalue of $p(A)$ does *not* imply that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.